# Numerical Solution of the Extended Nernst–Planck Model

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

I am trying to model an electrochemical system consisting of multiple ions. The model that fits my work the best is "the Extended Nernst–Planck Model". There is a numerical solution in the literature (https://doi.org/10.1006/jcis.1999.6145) and it involves finite-element method with a Galerkin weighting. Setting the matrix seems to be pretty straight forward, however, I am having difficulty in understanding the subsequent numerical manipulation. For example, calculating the variation in the matrix. I can't seem to find any resources (numerical method books, papers, etc.) that can provide a detailed procedure of how to numerically approach such a model. I wonder if anyone can guide me to such references.

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com